# android Gps Alert status

Tags: android, android-gps

I am checking in GPS status (is it active or passive) on My application,When Gps is closed, Alert Prompt Dialog opens and it asked **"for a better experience turn on device location which uses google's location service"**  and When I click **No Thanks or Ok** it doesn't fall inside of onActivityResult method,how can I handle result of alert prompt dialog? I shared GpsUtils class at below

```
public class GpsUtils extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Context context;
    private SettingsClient mSettingsClient;
    private LocationSettingsRequest mLocationSettingsRequest;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;

    public GpsUtils(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mSettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(context);
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(10 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(2 * 1000);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();
//**************************
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient
        //**************************
    }
    // method for turn on GPS
    public void turnGPSOn(final onGpsListener onGpsListener) {
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            if (onGpsListener != null) {
                onGpsListener.gpsStatus(true);
            }
        } else {
            mSettingsClient
                    .checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest)
                    .addOnSuccessListener((Activity) context, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
                        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
//  GPS is already enable, callback GPS status through listener
                            if (onGpsListener != null) {
                                onGpsListener.gpsStatus(true);
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener((Activity) context, new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            int statusCode = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
                            switch (statusCode) {
                                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                                    try {
                                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the
                                        // result in onActivityResult().
                                        ResolvableApiException rae = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                                        rae.startResolutionForResult((Activity) context, AppConstants.GPS_REQUEST);
                                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sie) {
                                        Log.i(TAG, "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                                    String errorMessage = "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be " +
                                            "fixed here. Fix in Settings.";
                                    Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
                                    Toast.makeText((Activity) context, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == AppConstants.GPS_REQUEST) {
                isGPS = true; // flag maintain before get location
                getLocation();
//                isContinue = true;
                stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            }
        }else{

            Main.this.finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public interface onGpsListener {
        void gpsStatus(boolean isGPSEnable);
    }
}
```